# Locking the screen when laptop lid is shut (Gnome 3.8, Fedora 19)

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, screensaver

I cannot figure out how to configure the screensaver to be run (which in turn causes the screen to be locked) every time I shut the lid of my laptop. I have xscreensaver installed and on Xfce it allowed me to configure an action when the lid is shut. Well, not on Gnome 3 :-( Any ideas?

**Edit**: I do not want the computer to suspend/hibernate when I shut the lid; simply blank the screen.

Answer (score 4):

From this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/748482/how-to-suspend-from-lockscreen-in-gnome-3 , in your `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` change the line to:

```
HandleLidSwitch=lock
```

and then `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind` to restart the service.

Answer (score 1):

in your /etc/systemd/logind.conf file, add the line

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

or if that doesn't work,

```
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
```

Source: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html

Comment: Don't know if it matters but he's on Fedora.

Comment: Releated: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=292190. That variable can also take the value `lock`.

Comment: Agreed that comment was more to guard you if others come along in the future and see the difference they'll know that it was already addressed by your follow-up comment. I also provided a link to fedoraforum with the same solution for added protection.

Comment: Yes, that would work if I wanted the machine to suspend. But I simply want to blank the screen and lock it at the same time when I shut the lid, not suspend.